# Target Facebook login button

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I'm newly learning the automation stuff, How can I target the Facebook login button.

```
<div class="fb-btn">
<div class="fb-logo"></div>
<div class="fb-text">Log In with Facebook</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

1 . @browser.div(:class => 'fb-btn').click

or

2. @browser.div(:class => 'fb-text').click

Answer (score 0):

This is the tag I found for log in button --

```
@browser.label(:id => "loginbutton").click
```

This should do it.

Or here is the full code to log in:

```
@browser.text_field(:id => 'email').set 'email@gmail.com'
@browser.text_field(:id => 'pass').set 'hardToGuess'
@browser.label(:id => "loginbutton").click
```